# Table dentro de celda de GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

¿Se puede crear dinámicamente una `Table` dentro de una celda de la `gridView`?

Sé que dentro de una `Table` puedes meter dentro de las celdas nuevas `table`, pero, ¿podría hacer lo mismo con una `gridView`?

Answer (score 3):

Podrias tener un GridView dentro de otro si es es lo que buscas, o quizas un Repeater

[Nested GridView Example in ASP.Net using C# and VB.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Nested-GridView-Example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

como veras el grid se crea como una nueva row que puedes colapsar para desplegar un detalle de datos relacionados a cada row

El truco esta en hacer uso del evento `RowDataBound` para poder seleccionar el control anidado usando el `FindControl()` y asignarle datos. El colapsable despues solo es codigo javascript o jquery que permite ocultarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion, Vere lo que puedo hacer e ire comentando por SO

Comment: Realmente el tema es que yo hago una consulta a la base de datos, y me devuelve un resultado, y una de las celdas del resultado tengo que dividirla en en variaceldas. Cuando uso `webControls.Table`puedo dividir la celda en varias celdas y agregarlas a la nueva `table` y despues esa `table` metarla en una celda. Mi pregunta era si podia realizar lo mismo pero con una `GridView`